# select top 1 from different sub queries to implement basic item routing function

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to implement a very simple routing system, which allows an item to go from one step to another, based on the routing information from related tables. My ASP.NET method should get the next step based on a database result, in order to avoid any stupid hardcoded values.

There is a table that contains the active steps (all steps "to do", or not to do, bit: 1 or 0) and another one with the completed steps. Based on this information I believe I should be able to do a select top 1 (the next step) from the table containing all the active steps, where the stepID is not in the list of already completed stepIDs.

I have tried this on paper and it made sense, I have also tried to work my way up from the detailed queries to the big query, which should return the next step (top 1). The bottom level queries work, however, I am having problems with my big query that should return the top 1 item (next step). I always get the following error:

> "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1. Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'WHERE'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1. Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'NOT'. (Line 4)"

Table overview as follows.

**Table *Routes* containing all steps to be done** (or not -> 0)

```
itemID |routeID |stepID |stepScheduled |
-------|--------|-------|--------------|
1      |1       |10     |1             |
2      |1       |20     |1             |
3      |1       |30     |1             |
4      |1       |40     |1             |
5      |1       |50     |1             |
6      |1       |60     |1             |
7      |1       |70     |1             |
8      |1       |80     |1             |
9      |1       |90     |1             |
10     |1       |100    |1             |
----------------------------------------
```

**Table *Steps_Completed* containing the steps that are completed** (could be empty if this item has not completed any steps yet).

```
completionID |sampleID |stepID |userName |completionDT        |stationID     |
-------------|---------|-------|---------|--------------------|--------------|
1            |1        |10     |Me       |2017-12-28 10:04:41 |workstation 1 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Query I am currently trying that is returning the error message mentioned above:

```
SELECT TOP 1 stepID FROM 
(SELECT [stepID] **Routes** WHERE [routeID] = 1 AND [stepScheduled] = 1) 
WHERE stepID NOT IN (SELECT stepID FROM **Steps_Completed** WHERE sampleID = 
1);
```

The sub queries in () work when executed separately and return the expected values:

- (SELECT [stepID] from **Routes** WHERE [routeID] = 1 AND [stepScheduled] = 1) 
  Returns all rows as seen in the first table (all "to do")
- (SELECT stepID FROM **Steps_Completed** WHERE sampleID = 
  1)
  Returns all rows that have been completed or an empty result if nothing has been recorded yet.

The idea was to do a basic "substraction" of the "Route" list, "minus" the completed steps and then selecting the top 1 item of the remaining list. Since the list of stepIDs can be ordered by ASC, then the top 1 item should be my result.

The problem appears to be with the *"WHERE stepID NOT IN"* part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the immediate fix to your current query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [stepID]
FROM Routes
WHERE
    [routeID] = 1 AND
    [stepScheduled] = 1 AND
    [stepID] NOT IN (SELECT stepID FROM Steps_Completed WHERE sampleID = 1)
ORDER BY
    [stepID];
```

Another way to phrase this would be using a left join:

```
SELECT TOP 1 r.stepID
FROM Routes r
LEFT JOIN Steps_Completed s
    ON r.routeID = s.sampleID AND
       r.stepID = s.stepID
WHERE
    r.routeID = 1 AND
    r.stepScheduled = 1 AND
    s.sampleID IS NULL
ORDER BY
    r.stepID;
```

One key point to note here is that we generally must use `ORDER BY` along with `TOP`.  Otherwise, the "top" is not well defined, as SQL tables have no internal order.  Also, I don't think you need to necessarily use a subquery here, so I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Alias:

```
SELECT TOP 1 stepID FROM 
(SELECT [stepID] from Routes WHERE [routeID] = 1 AND [stepScheduled] = 1) as a
WHERE stepID NOT IN (SELECT stepID FROM Steps_Completed WHERE sampleID = 
1);
```

Comment: Accepted @Tim's answer since he was quicker. Your answer works as well (tested), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stepID 
FROM Routes
WHERE stepID = (SELECT MIN(stepId) 
                FROM Routes r
                LEFT JOIN Steps_Completed sc
                ON r.stepID = sc.stepID
                WHERE [routeID] = 1 
                      AND [stepScheduled] = 1
                      AND sc.stepID is null)
```